# Use AT command in shell script

Tags: php, shell, at-command

I'm using gsm modem to send sms, via a terminal there's no problem but i want to write a shell script (called by php) and i want to know how insert AT command in.

**Example :**

> - call the script.sh
> - the script open minicom (sudo..)
> - type : AT+CMGS="num" + ENTER + "Message" + ctrl+Z
>     and send the sms to the num.

Thank you
Victor

Comment: The reason this question gets downvotes is that without any code it appears at first glance as a "please do the work for me" question, and Stackoverflow is not the place for such. With a little effort I able to read a valid question, but it is easy to overlook for someone just spending a couple of seconds reading it and then downvote.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being<sup>1</sup> I think your best option here is to use the programming language [expect](/questions/tagged/expect). It is written to monitor growing text output and support scenarios like

1. Wait for the string `"Username:"` to appear in the output.
2. Send the string `"my_name"`.
3. Wait for the string `"Password:"` to appear in the output.
4. Send the string `"my_secret_password"`.

Sending AT command and waiting for the response is very similar, so this is absolutely doable. When I worked at Ericsson we had a test suite written in expect that sent AT commands and parsed log files to run tests.

---

<sup>1</sup>
As a companion to my [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program, I have started to write a program to send the command AT+CMGS and its payload correctly. But unless you are very, very patient you should not wait for this to be finished.